# While loop / if statement combined with user input PYTHON

Tags: python, if-statement, random, while-loop

The user should be able to choose between having a random (between 0.2 and 0.5) disease factor, and inputting their own. I tried to use a while loop to set it off, and then have an if statement for the Y or N choice. However once the disease value has been set, it doesn't appeal to the original Y or N disease factor criteria, so loops back again and asks whether the user wants to input their own disease factor or not. I can see why it is going wrong, but I'm not sure what to put instead.

Additionally when the user selects "N", there is an error saying

```
while random_disease < 0.2 or random_disease > 0.5 :
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < float()
```

I don't understand why this is coming up, as I set random_disease originally as a number, and it's inside the loop regarding numbers, not Y or N.

Sorry about the pre-set indentation, it's taken straight from my current code which has lots of loops, functions etc in it.
Any help?

```
# Random disease factor #
        random_disease = 12
        while random_disease != "Y" or random_disease != "N":
            random_disease = input("Do you want a random disease factor? Enter Y if you do, or N if you want to select it yourself. Remember this will be between 0.2 and 0.5")
            if random_disease == "Y":
                random_disease = random.uniform(0.2, 0.5)
            elif random_disease == "N":
                while random_disease < 0.2 or random_disease > 0.5 :
                    try:
                        random_disease = float(input("What is your selected disease factor? Remember this should be between 0.2 and 0.5 : "))
                    except ValueError as ex:
                        print(ex)
            print("Your disease is ", random_disease)
```

Comment: If you picture the flow of the code, it seems that you're resetting the random_disease to a float, when the while loop evaluates it as a string. Therefore, even though you input a Y/N, it gets overwritten with a numeric type. Solution is to create another variable that the while loop evaluates: e.g: `while ask != 'Y' and ask != 'N'`

Comment: Looking at your solution and the code that makes sense - having one variable for the whole loop really doesn't work does it! I've tried again with your suggestions and it works perfectly now. Thanks very much. I can't select your comment to be the solution, could you copy and paste it (or something) in the other section so the post is rated better? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you picture the flow of the code, it seems that you're resetting the random_disease to a float, when the while loop evaluates it as a string. Therefore, even though you input a Y/N, it gets overwritten with a numeric type. Solution is to create another variable that the while loop evaluates: e.g: while `ask != 'Y' and ask != 'N'`

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic problem. Your while statement will *always* be true; if `random_disease` is "Y" it will not be "N", and vice versa. You need `and` there, not `or`.